# XSLT to Concatenate Empty Values

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, is-empty

We have a requirement that requires us to list out all the empty values from the incoming xml. I have searched but all I could find was listing non-null values, trying to use that for our xml is not returning the required results.

Here is the xml that we will receive and I want to be able to concatenate all the null values from this xml and print. Kindly assist.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<Output>
<Rows>
    <ns0:I2NA xmlns:ns0 = "http://www.example.com/schemas/Schema.xsd">
        <ns0:Organization>108</ns0:Organization>
        <ns0:AccountNumber>1231231231231231233 </ns0:AccountNumber>
        <ns0:Status>0</ns0:Status>
        <ns0:VipStatus>0</ns0:VipStatus>
        <ns0:TypeOfIdNo>1</ns0:TypeOfIdNo>
        <ns0:IdNo>2303111450               </ns0:IdNo>
        <ns0:HomePhone>123456              </ns0:HomePhone>
        <ns0:Employer>                                        </ns0:Employer>
        <ns0:EmployersPhone>123456              </ns0:EmployersPhone>
        <ns0:FaxPhone>123456              </ns0:FaxPhone>
        <ns0:MobileNo>0568520421          </ns0:MobileNo>
        <ns0:CountryCode>   </ns0:CountryCode>
        <ns0:PostalCode>          </ns0:PostalCode>
        <ns0:Position>    </ns0:Position>
        <ns0:MaritalStatus>0</ns0:MaritalStatus>
        <ns0:DateOfBirth>00000000</ns0:DateOfBirth>
        <ns0:EmailAddrs>                                                            </ns0:EmailAddrs>
        <ns0:UserCode1>  </ns0:UserCode1>
        <ns0:NationalityCode>   </ns0:NationalityCode>
        <ns0:NameLine1>ABC     </ns0:NameLine1>
        <ns0:NameLine2>                                        </ns0:NameLine2>
        <ns0:NameLine3>                                        </ns0:NameLine3>
        <ns0:ChDob>        </ns0:ChDob>
        <ns0:AddressLine1>USA                                   </ns0:AddressLine1>
        <ns0:AddressLine2>USA                                   </ns0:AddressLine2>
        <ns0:AddressLine3>USA                                   </ns0:AddressLine3>
        <ns0:AddressLine4>USA                                   </ns0:AddressLine4>
        <ns0:City>                              </ns0:City>
        <ns0:State>   </ns0:State>
        <ns0:GenderCode>0</ns0:GenderCode>
        <ns0:StatementNotifIndi> </ns0:StatementNotifIndi>
        <ns0:Nationality>                    </ns0:Nationality>
        <ns0:County>                              </ns0:County>
        <ns0:LastName>John                             </ns0:LastName>
        <ns0:MiddleName>                                        </ns0:MiddleName>
        <ns0:FirstName>SHAN MATHEW                             </ns0:FirstName>
        <ns0:LangPref>   </ns0:LangPref>
    </ns0:I2NA>
</Rows>
<EOF>true</EOF>
```

When the XSLT is applied, we would like to receive the below string as output.

```
Status,Employer,CountryCode,PostalCode,Position,EmailAddrs,UserCode1,NationalityCode,NameLine2,NameLine3,ChDob,City,State,StatementNotifIndi,Nationality,County,MiddleName,LangPref
```

Thanks!

Comment: You use the terms "null" and "empty", but you don't say exactly what you mean by them. Are you using the two terms as synonyms?

Comment: Yes Michael. I mean them as synonyms. Basically I want to list all the empty elements and list them down so that the support team can fix the issues in the stream and send back the data with no element missing. As each of these elements are mandatory at our end to process.

Comment: OK, judging from your examples, "empty" and "null" mean "contain nothing other than whitespace characters". You need to be more precise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<xsl:value-of select="//*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]/local-name()" separator=","/>`. But I don't understand why your sample string starts with `Status` while the XML has a value `<ns0:Status>0</ns0:Status>` for that field.

With XSLT 1.0 you need a bit of more code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>.</xsl:text></xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Sorry for that. Status inclusion in the list a typo :). I will check this and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a bunch Martin. It works! But I have a crib that it is working when I change the version of xslt to 2.0 and my TIBCO Designer by default supports 1.0 (of course, changing to 2.0 is working with Saxon -B Xslt that TIBCO is currently supporting).
Is there a similar way for xslt 1.0?

Comment: @tibuser, I have appended an XSLT 1.0 sample to the answer.